# Do not show in Add/Remove Programs until main installation is complete

Tags: wpf, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I have a WiX Custom Bootstrapper (WPF) composed of two MSI packages:

1. prerequisites
2. main installer

The problem is, when the prerequisite package installs, the bootstrapper's name already appears in Add/Remove programs even though the full installation is not yet completed. Is it possible to prevent the bootstrapper from showing in the list until the main installer (second package) has completed installing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, Burn always registers a bundle so it can handle reboots and finish installing.